# Swift - Video file array save to app gallery fine but not properly to the app document directory

Tags: arrays, swift, video, directory, save

I am trying to save an array of videos using a for loop to the document directory and gallery but the document directory is only saving the last video whereas the gallery has all of them saved without issues.

Any ideas how can this be fixed? Thanks for the input!

```
func saveVideoToGallery(videoUrl: String) {

 //currently a URL placeholder
    let videoMainUrl = 
 "https://dev.server.com/storage/sessions/0001/imports/"
    let videoUrlPicked = String(videoMainUrl + videoUrl)

    let mainPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
    let folderPath = mainPath + "/ImportVideo"
    var objCBool:ObjCBool = true


    // Create Directory Folder if  doesn't exists
    let isExist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: folderPath, isDirectory: &objCBool)
    if !isExist {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: folderPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        if let url = URL(string: videoUrlPicked),
            let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
            let fileName = String(self.videoURL)
            let filePath = "\(documentsPath + "/ImportVideo")" + fileName

  //Save the video file to directory folder "ImportVideo"
            urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

    //Save to the gallery
           PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                }) { completed, error in
                    if completed {
                        print("Video is saved to gallery")
                    }
                }
           }
        }

    }
}
```

For Loop

```
videoList = videoArray()

    for videos in videoList {

        saveVideoToGallery(videoUrl: videos)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem in these lines.

```
let fileName = String(self.videoURL)
let filePath = "\(documentsPath + "/ImportVideo")" + fileName
```

You're basically overwriting your video with the same `fileName` because every time it takes some global scope variable `self.videoURL` which I don't see chaining anywhere. Try to generate a unique file name for different videos for example using `UUID` string

`let fileName = UUID().uuidString`

Comment: Thanks Inokey! It does work now and saves in the right folder. I guess I will need to create a manifest to store the original name.